# Inserting ads into wordpress default rss feeds

Tags: rss, ads

i'm hoping i'd find some help in regards to inserting ads into wordpress default rss feeds (i do not use feedburner)

```
<?php
function insertAds($content) {
    $content = $content.'<hr /><a href="http://www.wprecipes.com">Have you visited WpRecipes today?</a><hr />';
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'insertAds');
add_filter('the_content_rss', 'insertAds');
?>
```

[Source here](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-insert-ads-on-your-rss-feed)

But i read that the_excerpt_rss and the_content_rss is kind of deprecated. Can anyone advise me on the present hooks to use?

Thanks

Comment: none of those are deprecated there still in use according to WordPress codex.

Comment: The codex discourages use of the_content_rss in favor of the_content_feed http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content_rss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [the_content_feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content_feed) as a replacement for the_content_rss.

Answer (score 1):

Those filters aren’t deprecated. They are used in `wp-includes/default-filters.php` too.

But you should [prefix your function name](http://andrewnacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/).

Comment: This should probably be a comment